# Работы с ProgressBar в паттерне MVVM

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, mvvm, devexpress

Есть проект:

**EGEModel.cs**

```
class EGEModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        private int _currentProgress;
        public int currentProgress
        {
            get { return _currentProgress; }
            set
            {
                if (_currentProgress != value)
                {
                    _currentProgress = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("currentProgress");
                }
            }
        }
        public void createReport()
        {
            currentProgress = 0;
            ... //
            currentProgress += 10;
            ... //
            currentProgress += 10;
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
...
<dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="createReportView" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" />
...
<dxb:BarEditItem Name="ProgressBar" EditValue="{Binding ege.currentProgress, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**Command.cs**

```
public class Command : ICommand
    {
        public Command(Action<object> action)
        {
            ExecuteDelegate = action;
        }

        public Predicate<object> CanExecuteDelegate { get; set; }
        public Action<object> ExecuteDelegate { get; set; }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (CanExecuteDelegate != null)
            {
                return CanExecuteDelegate(parameter);
            }

            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (ExecuteDelegate != null)
            {
                ExecuteDelegate(parameter);
            }
        }
    }
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public EGEModel ege { get; set; }
    public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ClickCommand = new Command(arg => ege.createReport());
    }

}
```

После нажатия на кнопку "createReport" происходят некие вычисления и прогресс бар "должен" увеличиваться по мере вычислений на 10 пунктов, но этого не происходит. Функция как бы запускается в блокирующем режиме. После ее выполнения уже видно полный заполненный ProgressBar. Как это исправить?

Comment: Ответ очевиден: не запускайте длинную функцию в блокирующем режиме. У вас небось весь UI виснет, правильно? Попробуйте во время вычислений перетащить окно программы.

Comment: Совершенно верно. А как мне запустить длинную функцию не в блокирующем режиме?  Мне ведь надо еще что-бы во время ее выполнения, пользователь не трогал интерфейс.

Comment: @derkode: Ну, заблокируйте интерфейс на это время, а как иначе?

Запустить проще всего через `Task.Run`, заодно можно будет использовать async/await, если что.

---
Для блокирования интерфейса можно либо перевести в состояние `Enabled="false"` все интересующие вас контролы, либо положить в UI сверху полупрозрачную панель во всё окно.

Comment: >Запустить проще всего через Task.Run, заодно можно будет использовать async/await, если что.

А заодно и IProgress<T>, который и выведет в нужную сторону :).

Answer (score 1):

Использовать также внешнее свойство. 
Пройдись по этой ссылке, тут есть пример.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520359/how-to-implement-a-progress-bar-using-the-mvvm-pattern

Comment: Добавте в ответ больше информации, можно с примером, а то заминусят сейчас

Comment: зачем копировать чужой текст? по ссылке все на "очевидном" английском написано))))

Comment: такие правила оформления ответов, иначе можно было бы добавить комментарием

Comment: А хорошо, учту в будущем.